# How to get currency code from InApp purchase using Electron's Mac AppStore integration?

Tags: javascript, electron, in-app-purchase, currency, mac-app-store

Is there a way to know exactly what currency a Mac AppStore user is seeing prices for using Electron? I'm having difficulty finding a clean way to do this.

I'm used to working with StoreKit directly, where you get currency separate from the price from the [priceLocale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct/1506145-pricelocale) object. Electron seems to mirror this really well, but if you compare the StoreKit's [SKProduct](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct) object and Electron's [Product](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/structures/product) object, you'll see that priceLocale is conspicuously missing...

Is there another way to get the currency of a Product in Electron? This is really baffling me.

EDIT: So it appears that since I made this question, Electron has added this in their latest 9.x.y packages. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/structures/product Now shows currencyCode as a field!